# Number in df column, but not in list version of that column

Tags: python, pandas, assert

I have the following code:

```py
    if 0 in df[RATING_COL]:
        rating_col_list = df[RATING_COL].to_list()
        assert 0 in rating_col_list
```

The assert is triggering an `AssertionError`. How can this be possible? **How can it be that there's a 0 in the column, but when I convert the column to a list, the 0 disappears?**

The dataframe I'm loading is based on MovieLens-1M and looks like:

```
user_id,item_id,rating
1,1193000,2
1,1193001,3
1,1193002,4
1,1193003,5
1,1193004,6
1,1193005,7
1,1193006,8
1,1193007,9
1,1193008,10
1,661000,6
1,661001,7
1,661002,8
1,661003,9
1,661004,10
1,661005,9
1,661006,8
1,661007,7
1,661008,6
```

In this format, `1,1193008,10` indicates that user 1 rated item 1193 with an 8. The 10 indicates that this is the rating, and all other items starting with 1193 will have a rating lower than 10. (So `1,661004,10` indicates that user 1 rated item 661 with a 4.)

(Also, I've checked with CTRL-F: there is no 0 rating in the rating column.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0 in df[RATING_COL]` searches in the **index**, to search in the Series **values** use:

```
if 0 in df[RATING_COL].values:
    rating_col_list = df[RATING_COL].to_list()
    assert 0 in rating_col_list
```

Answer (score 3):

> *How can it be that there's a 0 in the column .. ?*

Because `0` is an index of the Series `df[RATING_COL]`.

```
RATING_COL = "rating"

print(df[RATING_COL])

0      2 # <-- index 0
1      3
2      4
3      5
4      6
5      7
6      8
7      9
8     10
9      6
10     7
11     8
12     9
13    10
14     9
15     8
16     7
17     6
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```

It's like when checking if a key is in a dictionary, `O in d` will check if `0` is one of the keys of `d`.

Comment: I think this originally confused me precisely because I know that `0 in d` will check if 0 is one of the keys of `d`, but also `list(d)` will list the keys. For some reason, `df[RATING_COL].to_list()` does not list the indices, and instead lists the values. This is what tripped me up.